# Finding distinct subsets of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm struggling a bit with the terminology here, but I have a set of sets and I'm trying to find all the subsets always occur together. For example, in the set

$$
S = \{\{a,b,c\},\{a,b,c,d\},\{a,b,c,e\},\{d,e\}\}
$$

The subset $\{a,b,c\}$ would be such a set. Either this subset is present or none of its elements occur.

Is there a known algorithm to identify all such subsets? If I was to do more research on this, how would I succinctly describe this problem using set theory terminology? I want to edit this description to make it easier to find if anyone else is looking at a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let S = {{a,b,c}, {a,b,c,d}, {a,b,c,e}, {d,e}}.
{a,b,c} is not a subset of S.
It is an element or member of S.

Rewrite S = {A,B,C,D}.
Find the subsets of S:
{A}, {A,B}, {A,C},... etc.
Replace A, B, C, D with their values A = {a,b,c}, etc.
For example {A} = { {a,b,c} } is a subset of S.

Comment: Let me clarify, I'm trying to discover the subsets of the elements of $S$ that always occur together. Given _any_ such $S$, is there an algorithm to discover these subsets (of the elements of $S$).

Comment: @karim Elements of a set do not occur together  If you have a sequence (A, B, C, D), A & B,  B & C, C & D occur together.